# What is consuming over 65% of time in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I have an .Net Framework 4.0, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC 3 web application hosted on a Windows 7 / IIS 7.5. IIS logging is enabled on this machine and set to log in W3C mode.

The application is compiled by using the Release configuration and has been deployed to IIS with `<compilation debug='false'` attribute set explicitly. The Web.config specifies the use of SQL Server based session state.

I have added the following statements in Global.asax in BeginRequest and EndRequest events respectively. The results i.e. "sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds" are getting stored in an Application level list of values. I dump these values out via a debug page and get an average of the same.

```
// in BeginRequest
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("RequestStartEnd", System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew());

// in EndRequest
var sw = (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch)HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestStartEnd"];
sw.Stop();
```

I have created a load test which runs a single request against this application with a concurrent user load of 20 users. The test is run in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition.

After running the load test, I am getting an average time-taken as recorded by the stopwatch as 681 milliseconds.The average time-taken as per IIS for these requests (I cleaned out all logs before running the load test) is 2121 milliseconds. The average time-taken as per IIS tallys with the value shown in Visual Studio load test report.

The stopwatch time-taken only accounts for 32% of time-taken as reported by IIS logs / Visual Studio. Where does the other 68% time go?

**Update 1:**
I set the session state to InProc and re-ran the load test. In this scenario the difference between the average time reported by stopwatch and average time-taken reported by IIS logs grew to more than 70%!!! Where is all that time going?

**Update 2:**
@Peter - I tried out the failed request tracing by putting a trace rule to log on status code of 200. Next, I ran the load test with 20 concurrent users for approx 1.5 minutes. Went through last 50 trace files and found that the "Time Taken" field in that report had range of 750ms to 1300ms. The Visual Studio report showed avg. time taken as 2300ms. In the report, using the compact view, I see that the time taken changes between the following transitions 
    (1) AspNetStart -> AspNetAppDomainEnter 
    (2) ManagedPipelineHandler-start ManagedPipelineHandler-end. 
The (2) item is probably my application's code. Still there is a big difference between max of time-taken as per failed request logs i.e. 1300ms and the avg. time-taken as shown by Visual Studio 2300ms. How to find accounting for that? Thanks for this great tip though!

Comment: You should look into profiling your code.  It will give you much more granular and directly usable data than simple stopwatch based performance counters.

Comment: @Merlyn - I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate profiler for the same. Will try to see the reports with "Show All Code" turned on. However, I suspect that the issue may lie in IIS rather than ASP.NET and hence may not be covered in the profiling. The reason behind the suspicion is that the the stopwatch timing is taken in ASP.NET's request-start and request-end events.

Comment: Have you considered system-level factors outside of ASP.NET? e.g. IIS overhead, network? Added more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

How long are you running your load test for?  If you're running it under windows 7 you may get different results than under a windows server as well.  You could be having issues with getting threads allocated to the thread pool under burst loads.  .Net will immediately allocate threads up to the thread pool min and then slowly allocate up to the thread pool max.  I believe the default settings for client OS's are different than for server OS's.  It may be on a client OS the default min thread setting is equal to the number of cores on your machine, meaning that .net will then slowly allocate more threads to meet your burst load.

A simple check would be to let your load test run longer and see if the gap between your 2 measurements narrows.

Comment: The tests were carried out on a Windows 7 machine with IIS 7.5. The load test was run under constant load of 20 users. I will try running it on the same machine for a longer period and will post back results.

Comment: Here's information on how to change min/max worker/io thread settings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx.  One semi gotcha to be aware of is you need to disable the autoconfig otherwise your new values will be ignored.

Comment: Another consideration in your test is that if you are starting a cold site, the first request is going to incur all sorts of time penalties associated with jitting, etc.  If you start cold with burst of requests, they are all going to queue until the site is ready.  So especially if you aren't warming up your site and have a short test duration, your results are going to be skewed.

Comment: I am warming up the application manually before running the load tests.

Comment: While the load tests are running, I see almost 100% CPU utilization - so am not sure if increasing worker/IO threads will help. Also, the question still stands as to where the missing 65% of the time goes. If we assume that all processing for managed requests happen between begin-requst and end-request, then we can reasonably assume that there should be very less amount of time spent in IIS and hence the values should be much more closer togather. 65% is a significant amount of time that goes missing.

Comment: If you're running at 100 percent cpu, you would probably benefit from hosting your site on a different box than the test execution engine.  I'm guessing that your 65 percent of time spent outside of asp.net is spent queued in iis because there isn't a thread available to take the request due to the burst nature of your testing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to look into the internals of your app, by using "Failed Request Tracing Rules"

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/

With that you can follow exactly what you app is doing in IIS

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into MvcMiniProfiler. It's a NuGet package you could add and wire in (almost effortlessly) that really breaks down the execution times of various points in your MVC app. You could see a live view of each request and where any bottlenecks reside.

More info:

- http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx
- http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/MiniProfiler

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely a combination of the ***Managed Pipeline*** overhead and your ***network*** (even localhost or 127.0.0.1) is probably where the "lost" time can be accounted for.

1. You mention that the IIS logs tally with your Visual Studio load
   test figures - both of those involve the network stack and the managed pipleline.
2. Your stopwatch code only executes inside the ASP.NET context (just
   before ASP.NET execution begins and just before it ends), and does not take into account
   the IIS overhead of processing a TCP network request, parsing
   HTTP-headers for both the request and response and transmission time
   through the managed pipeline and TCP stack.
3. **[EDIT]** The proportion is exaggerated even more if your ASP.NET page execution time is really fast, e.g. it does not consume a lot of CPU relative to the rest of the TCP stack and managed pipeline that marshals the HTTP request for you

Answer (score 1):

if you are having issues with long load times it may be related to several things if you have a  high number of IO operations it can affect this
if you are doing database queries with an orm try profiling your sql statements either in vs with a sql profiler or in sql servers built in profiler if you are getting alot of individual querys you may want to consider using some includes in you linq queries to bundle up some of your data into single queries

you may also want to consider want to consider using async controllers to improve response times if you have alot of IO operations so your application isnt continuously waiting for each io operation to complete 
see  [wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/03/29/…](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/03/29/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

there also better solutions out there for logging than the iis logging as it is a fairly old component you may want to take a look at log4net for more general logging or elmah for logging errors and exceptions as these solutions can bundle up a bunch of log entries and write several in a single operation also improving IO performance

Comment: Waiting for IO in code should be accounted for in the Stopwatch timings - so there shouldnt be a gap between what is reported in IIS and what is reported by stopwatch.